# NGRX EFFECTS Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'EffectResult<Action>'

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

what do i do wrong?

```
  fetchEmail$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(RDX_EMAIL_CONFIRM_FETCH),
    switchMap(ac => axios.post(axiosInstance.post('/api/email-confirm/check-email', {
      email: ac.payload.email
    }).then(res => {
      return {
        type: RDX_EMAIL_CONFIRM_FETCH_SUCCESS,
      };
    }).catch(err => {
      return {
        type: RDX_EMAIL_CONFIRM_FETCH_ERROR
      };
    })))
  ))
```

would noah like to call some api and return an action based on that?
unfortunatley has the following error

```
Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'EffectResult<Action>'.
  Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>'.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Action'
```

here's my reducer maby the problem occurs here
Is it the actions payload definition?

```
import { createAction, createReducer, on, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { tassign } from 'tassign';

export const RDX_EMAIL_CONFIRM_FETCH = 'RDX_EMAIL_CONFIRM_FETCH';
export const RDX_EMAIL_CONFIRM_FETCH_SUCCESS = 'RDX_EMAIL_CONFIRM_FETCH_SUCCESS';
export const RDX_EMAIL_CONFIRM_FETCH_ERROR = 'RDX_EMAIL_CONFIRM_FETCH_ERROR';

export const rdxEmailConfirmFetch = createAction(
  RDX_EMAIL_CONFIRM_FETCH,
  props<{email: string}>()
);
export const rdxEmailConfirmFetchSuccess = createAction(RDX_EMAIL_CONFIRM_FETCH_SUCCESS);
export const rdxEmailConfirmFetchError = createAction(RDX_EMAIL_CONFIRM_FETCH_ERROR);

const initialState = {
  isFetch: false
}
export const emailConfirmReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(rdxEmailConfirmFetch, (state) => tassign(state, {
    isFetch: true
  })),
  on(rdxEmailConfirmFetchSuccess, (state) => tassign(state, {
    isFetch: false
  })),
  on(rdxEmailConfirmFetchError, (state) => tassign(state, {
    isFetch: false
  }))
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use RxJS `of` operator to convert it to observable, just like below.

```
  fetchEmail$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(RDX_EMAIL_CONFIRM_FETCH),
    switchMap(ac => axios.post(axiosInstance.post('/api/email-confirm/check-email', {
      email: ac.payload.email
    }).then(res => {
      return of({
        type: RDX_EMAIL_CONFIRM_FETCH_SUCCESS,
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      return of({
        type: RDX_EMAIL_CONFIRM_FETCH_ERROR
      });
    })))
  ))
```